# Process Controlling

Tags: c++, c, unix, fork

So I'm trying to do my programming assignment, here it is:

```
Write a C/C++ program (call it string invert) that takes a
string argument from the command line and outputs the string in reversed order. Here comes
the twist: Each process can output at most one character. If you want to output more than a
single character, you must fork off one or more processes in order to do that, and each of the
forked processes in turn outputs a single character. After the call to program string invert
with the command line argument, the output should appear, and no more processes should
be running, in addition to the shell. Test your program on any UNIX/LINUX machine, and
turn in the source code as part of the written assignment. (The source code should be at
most a few lines long.)
```

I can do the read and invert string easy, no problem. The problem is what does it mean when it says "each process can output at most one character". i don't even understand what that means. I don't need any code, i'm confident i can do it myself once i understand. I just need someone to explain what that's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the input "abcd", then your program should spawn a process for each character. So the first process would return 'd', the second process 'c' and so on. The assignment is probably a test of how well you understand synchronizing processes.

Answer (score 1):

Every process should jsut print *ONE* character. Example:

```
$yourProgamm sample
```

usually you would loop over the sample string and simply print each character with a call to `cout` or so. However you are supposed to only print one character per process. Meaning you output `e`, everything is fine. But if you run the loop again to output `l` the same process printed a second character.

So you have to *fork* a process for *each* character, let that process print that *one* character and continue your loop. Be sure to synchronize with `join` else you might get random order output (I guess this is the main point of the assignment, just run it a couple of times without it to see what I mean).